# Почему в конструкторе блока "Поделиться" нет нужного мне сервиса?

Tags: javascript, share, ya-share2

Мне нужно добавить кнопку Telegramm, но её нет в [конструкторе](https://tech.yandex.ru/share/) блока.

Как проверить, какие кнопки поддерживаются блоком на текущий момент?

Comment: https://tech.yandex.ru/share/ где вы тут нашли телеграм? Задайте этот вопрос в саппорт яндекса

Comment: @AlexeyTen Саппорт рекомендует задавать вопросы на SO. Я поправил вопрос, чтобы всем было понятно, о чём речь.

Answer (score 3):

Актуальный список поддерживаемых соцсетей можно найти в [документации](https://tech.yandex.ru/share/doc/dg/add-docpage/#supported-networks).

Telegram (с одной m) в этом списке есть, подключить его можно так:

```
<div class="ya-share2" data-services="telegram">
```

В конструкторе кнопки могут появляться с некоторой задержкой, так что при любых сомнениях надо в первую очередь обращаться к документации.